# Versioning of multimoduled applications

Tags: c#, .net, module, unity-container

In a moduled application the main project mainly registers and initializes other modules. It almost never changes except when new modules are added. In such cases, version number of the application is not relevant to any of the program's components.

In my app (13 modules, C#, .NET 4, unity container) I'm using an xml file to set version number of the product.

What are the best practices in versionng of multimoduled products?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best practices vary depending on the needs of the application or environment.

For example, one of our application suites consists of 12 applications comprised of numerous modules. All of the applications communicate to a central application server using a variety of protocols (.Net Remoting, Web Services, WCF) and from there to a central database. Because of the high correlation between the database, application server, and applications, they are all on the same major and minor version levels; only the revision level is allowed to differ.

However, in scenarios where the correlation is not high, as it sounds like in your application, version matching does not sound nearly as important. However, there are other considerations to keep in mind such as marketing needs: do you really want to be on version 1 forever even though from a technical standpoint there is no reason to change the version?